# Show only differences in statements

Tags: prolog

```
reservation("8V32EU", "John", "Doe", "27B", "YYZ", "CPH", "SAS").
reservation("8V32EU2", "Jane", "Doe", "27B", "YYZ", "CPH", "SAS").
reservation("94ISCU", "John", "Doe", "2C", "CPH", "YYZ", "SAS").
reservation("FDSDD3", "John", "Doe", "12D", "YYZ", "ROU", "SAS").
```

Say I have these statements.

There was a glitch and John and Jane booked the same seat on the same flight. (first two statements).
How can I write a procedure that returns the reservation codes of the double reserved seats? (in this case "8V32EU" and "8V32EU2"). I need to compute the booking code of all double bookings essentially

My attempt so far:

```
double_reservations(BookingCode, SeatNo, Fname, Lname) :-
   reservation(BookingCode, Fname, Lname, SeatNo, _, _, _).
```

however this only works if you give it the seat in question:

```
double_reservations(BookingCode, "27B", _, _).
```

is there a way without it ? Only `double_reservations(BookingCode, _, _, _).`

Comment: so you mean check that the origin airports, destination airports and airlines are the same as well?

Comment: any suggestions? I dont know how to do this in prolog

Comment: can you maybe write the procedure in a comment? I am not sure how to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried this ```kek(SeatNo, OAir, DAir, Airline, BookingCode) :- findall(BCode, reservation(BCode, _, _, SeatNo, OAir, DAir, Airline), BookingCode).``` but it just shows all the reservations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should separate the identification of problematic reservation codes, and then recover whatever details are needed from reservation/7 table:

```
double_reservations(BookingCode1, BookingCode2) :-
   reservation(BookingCode1, _Fname1, _Lname1, SeatNo, OAir, DAir, Airline),
   reservation(BookingCode2, _Fname2, _Lname2, SeatNo, OAir, DAir, Airline),
   BookingCode1 \= BookingCode2.
```

Comment: This returns both A,B and B,A. If you use `@<` in the last line instead you get only one.

Comment: @TomasBy: you're right, of course. I was more interested in illustrating the most basic relational schema.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. What do you mean use ```@<``` ?

Comment: `(@<)/2` it's a term generalized comparison operator. It works predictably on grounds terms. In your example, some examples are `"8V32EU", "John", "Doe",` Since it breaks symmetry, it avoid (some) repetitions, while the symmetric operator (\=)/2, means **don't unify**, doesn't discard them from search tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using `findall/3` or `setof/3`. Here a solution using `findall/3`:

```
getDouble([]).
getDouble([HS|TS]):-
    findall(C,reservation(C,_,_,HS,_,_,_),LC),
    length(LC,N),
    (   N > 1 ->  
        writeln(LC) 
    ; true),
    getDouble(TS).

solve:-
    findall(S,reservation(_,_,_,S,_,_,_),LS),
    sort(LS,L),
    getDouble(L).
```

Query:

```
?- solve.
[8V32EU, 8V32EU2]
true
```

I used `findall/3` and `sort/2` to remove duplicates ([read this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2)), instead of `setof/3` because `findall/3` will return an empty list if the goal has no solutions, whereas `setof/3` (and `bagof/3`) would fail in such a situation ([link](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse49)). If you don't want to remove duplicates you can use `msort/2`.